# .net core 6.0 on CentOS installs wrong version

Tags: .net, centos8

These are 2 commands I ran trying to install .net core 6.0 on CentOS 8 Stream:

```
sudo dnf install dotnet-runtime-6.0
Last metadata expiration check: 0:12:04 ago on Tue 23 Nov 2021 17:38:47 UTC.

. . .

Installed:
  dotnet-host-6.0.0-0.6.28be3e9a006d90d8c6e87d4353b77882829df718.el8.x86_64                                                                                
  dotnet-hostfxr-6.0-6.0.0-0.6.28be3e9a006d90d8c6e87d4353b77882829df718.el8.x86_64                                                                         
  dotnet-runtime-6.0-6.0.0-0.6.28be3e9a006d90d8c6e87d4353b77882829df718.el8.x86_64                                                                         
  lttng-ust-2.8.1-11.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                            
  userspace-rcu-0.10.1-4.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                        

Complete!

[/usr/local/bin]$  dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0-rc.2.21470.23 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Install says it installed `6.0.0-0.6` but the actual version is `6.0.0-rc.2.21470.23` and my app is failing with error:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.0' (x64) was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      6.0.0-rc.2.21470.23 at [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

**Can it be fixed without manual .net install ?**

Comment: Same problem here :(